# Change label with button

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uilabel

I have no idea how I can get stuck on this simple thing, but I can't get my button to change my label. What have I missed?

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *quoteButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *quoteLabel;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

#pragma mark - User Interaction

- (IBAction)quoteButtonPressed {
  self.quoteLabel.text = @"Hello World";
}

@end
```

Comment: r u connected your button in IBOUTLET else r u created in your button progrmatically

Comment: use nslog in - (IBAction)quoteButtonPressed to check whether action is bind to current function..  Also Check for label connection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may not connect IBAction for button.or IBOutlet connection for label  to interface builder.check it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem of a connection between button and function
try to click CTRL and drag the button to the function code to link them

Answer (score 0):

1. Whether quoteButtonPressed: method is executed. 
   You can try to make a breakpoint at the line of -(void)quoteButtonPressed: method.
   Then you run the project again, see Whether the project stops at the breakpoint line.
2. Did IBOutlet connect well? 
   There is any warnings about connections.
3. Lengthen quoteLabel.